# Internet Explorer 10 ignores width & height on images

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer-10

I have a website in which Internet Explorer 10 is completely ignoring the explicitly set width and height attributes in favour of the actual image size.

The image is defined as:

```
<img style="float: left; margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; display: inline;" 
     align="left" src="http://blog.hinshelwood.com/files/2012/09/metro-findings.png"
     width="64" 
     height="64"/>
```

But it is rendered as 128x128 in IE10. In Chrome it is just as you would expect.

E.g. http://blog.hinshelwood.com/tfs-integration-tools-issue-tfs-wit-invalid-submission-conflict-type/

On this page the "Applies To", "Solution" and "Findings" images are all set to 64x64 but in IE10 they display as 128x128. I have tried setting the following CSS, but this too is ignored:

```
h3 img {
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have

```
body .content img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto \9;
}
```

http://blog.hinshelwood.com/wp-content/themes/pagelines/pagelines-compiled-css-2_1348178943/

In IE, the invalid `width: auto \9;` is interpreted as `width: auto;`

In Chrome, the invalid width is ignored.

Without the width auto, the behaviour of the image is different:

In Chrome, the width is now derived from `h3 IMG { width: 64px; }`, and since the height is auto, the image is scaled according to 64px.

In IE, both width and height are still "auto", and thus it takes on the default IMG sizes.

**CSS styles overrides IMG tag attributes**: you can try using inline styling to override inherited styles.

```
<img style="height: 64px; width: 64px;" src="..." />
```

Comment: you are using inline attribute, not inline styles.

`<img style="height:64px; width: 64px;" .../>`

not

`<img height=64 width=64 ... />`

attributes for img are from the days of old before the time of CSS - CSS rules overrides traditional attributes.

Comment: Attributes should still technically override even in-line style! So IE is not folowing the standard... very amusing as this is how Live Writer sets width and height!

Comment: I added "!Important" to the "h3 img" to fix it :)

Comment: JohnLiu, @MrHinsh, I noticed that Wordpress uses attributes (width=600 height=900) for images and they supercede all styles in Internet Explorer, including IE11, which means max-width: 100% won't work when they are, regretfully, autogenerated by WP.